# many to many mapping spring jpa named entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa

This is one entity.

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.TicketType.subTypes",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "subTypes", subgraph = "subTypes"))
@Data
@Entity
public class TType extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String pubId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tTypes", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<TSubType> subTypes;
}
```

and the subType class:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class TSubType extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String pubId;

    @ManyToMany
    List<TType> tTypes;
}
```

I am not able to insert the data in TType using this json.

```
{
      "name": "BC-Tall",
      "pubId": "BC",
      "subTypes": [
        {
          "name": "Agg.",
          "pubId": "AGG"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Is there any error in my mapping?
I get this error: `Illegal use of mappedBy on both sides of the relationship`

What do I need to change to make this work through NamedEntityGraph ??

EDIT: I removed the bidirectional mapping. Now I can insert the data. 
However, when I retrieve there are no subTypes in TType. subTypes is an empty List.

Comment: You need to put "mappedBy" on ONE SIDE of the BIDIRECTIONAL relation ONLY, dependent on which side OWNS it, as per any JPA documentation. But then the error tells you that! http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#many_many_set

Comment: I did that. And updated the question. I get empty List in TType for subTypes.

Comment: So you then go DEBUG it, bu checking WHAT is in the database, and HOW you are retrieving it